# Continuous map from topological space $A\rightarrow B$ as composition of quotient map and unique continuous map from quotient space to $B$

Tags: general-topology, continuity, quotient-spaces

Let $(A,T_A)$ be a topological space; $R$ an equivalence relation; $Q=A/R$ the quotient set with $i:A\rightarrow Q$ the quotient map and $T_Q=\{V\subset Q|i^{-1}(V)\text{ open in $X$}\}$ the quotient topology.
Let $B$ be a topological space with $\phi:A\rightarrow B$ a continuous map such that for all $a,a'\in A$ we have $aRa'\implies\phi(a)=\phi(a')$.

> How do I prove that there exists exactly one continuous map $\psi:Q\rightarrow B$ with $\phi=\psi\circ i$?

What I know:
I know that if $aRa'$ then we get $i(a)=i(a')$. Would it be enough to define $\psi(i(a)):=\phi(a)$ and prove that it is continuous?
And how would I prove continuity and uniqueness?

Comment: You need to show that $\psi$ is well-defined by $\psi(i(a)) := \phi(a)$. Then you show that $\psi$ is continuous (use the universal property of the quotient topology). The uniqueness follows from the surjectivity of $i$.

Comment: @DanielFischer How would I show well-definedness?

Comment: You show that the value $\phi(a)$ doesn't depend on the choice of the representative $a$ of $i(a)$, i.e. you show $i(a) = i(a') \implies \phi(a) = \phi(a')$.